# Parsing Json Data inside Rounded Brackets using Python

Tags: python, json

Hello I need Output as SILVERM JUN FUT by parsing json response to symbol using Python

follow is the Json Response that I received

```
{'exchange': 'MCX', 'token': 221599, 'ltp': 71480.0, 'ltt': 1623072465, 'ltq': 1, 'volume': 20227, 'best_bid_price': 71476.0, 'best_bid_quantity': 2, 'best_ask_price': 71487.0, 'best_ask_quantity': 2, 'total_buy_quantity': 2086, 'total_sell_quantity': 2163, 'atp': 71205.04, 'exchange_time_stamp': 1623072466, 'open': 71380.0, 'high': 71550.0, 'low': 70890.0, 'close': 71585.0, 'yearly_high': 71550.0, 'yearly_low': 0.0, 'instrument': Instrument(exchange='MCX', token=221599, symbol='SILVERM JUN FUT', name='', expiry=datetime.date(2021, 6, 30), lot_size=None)}
```

as Instrument Data is contained in ( ) rounded brackets how can i parse beyond instrument object

Comment: Is this valid json with `Instrument(`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update: It was not python dict() as per the person who removed his comment. but a named tuple

following solution worked for me:

P = response['instrument']
print(P.symbol)